# Php Error when running drush in cygwin

Tags: php, drupal, cygwin, drush

in order to manipulate a theme in drupal I had to install Drush in order to make sub-theme. I installed cygwin and followed the tutorial in the link [drush installer in cygwin](https://www.drupal.org/node/1432756)

I am getting an error message in php which is as follow:
[image]

I Extensively searched google but failed to find a solution that worked. I even edited the drush.php file and hard-coded the link to bootstrap.inc but even that did not work. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do `which php` and `which drush` say?

Comment: I am sorry but I am am not understanding your question. Please bear with me as I am new to this.

Comment: @Kenney is asking to chedk the path of your php install. In your CLI, run "which php" and "which drush", each should return their respective insatll paths.

Comment: You may want to try running your drush commands within the docroot of your Drupal project.